# Multithreading java application is failing sometimes to get all threads on Websphere

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, websphere

I have an exhaustive java application (JRE 1.8.0_201) that requires to be executed in threads, It is deployed on IBM Websphere 9.

At WAS startup time the application executions seems to be fine, however sometimes later the multithreading capability is lost and the executions occurs using only one thread.

If we restart again the websphere the situation turns into normality, the executions takes again the proper parallel threads.

Is there some WAS configurations that I'm missing? or at java or OS side?

Below the HW architecture on Linux:

- Architecture: x86_64
- CPU op-mode (s): 32-bit, 64-bit
- Byte Order: Little Endian
- CPU (s): 4
- On-line CPU (s) list: 0-3
- Thread (s) per core: 1
- Core (s) per socket: 1
- Socket (s): 4

Comment: Very unlikely to be a hardware issue. You need to show how you're scheduling the threads. And is there any synchronisation or communication between threads? There could be race conditions, deadlocks or other bugs in any code that does that.

Comment: WebSphere has several thread pools that may need to be tuned in order to have the capacity for your specific needs.  If there is a thread exhaustion due to config or some other factor that Erwin mentioned, you should get a thread dump to see what the threads are all doing.  Also you can take a look at the "Thread Pools" and "Tune a Thread Pool" sections in the WebSphere Performance cook book here:  https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/ for some guidance on tuning thread pool in WebSphere.

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Comment: No yet @JRichardsz

Comment: How are you using threads? Allocating new ones yourself? Or you're talking about threads from one of WebSphere's pools?

Comment: Through Was @dbreaux

Comment: what about @Petr Freiberg answer?

Comment: One of the WAS thread pools? Which one? But you can use the thread dump/javacore to look through those threads and see where each is. My guess is threads stuck in some application code that eventually consume the entire pool.

Comment: Re. "sometimes later the multithreading capability is lost and the executions occurs using only one thread": Is the "one thread" always the main thread?

Comment: Do you have some ESB service bus? or Service Oriented Architecture? how you deploy your application? is it one `war` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get maximum information about the problem:

**Thread Dump**

Creates a listing of the current state of all threads within JVM. It’s advisable to do this listing repeatedly (in differently named outputs, don’t overwrite your dumps) within a few tens of seconds/minutes and in your case maybe hours. This allows you to capture changes and possible dead-lock. If nothing has changed and thread is on the same row, then there might be a problem.

**How to make thread dump:**

Open the console (CMD), switch to “/Java/jdkx.x.x_xx /bin” (JDK) using the “cd” command. Then type “jstack JVM_PID > /thread_dump_1“. Replace the “JVM_PID” with the process ID of running JVM (Task Manager – Details – PID column).

You can also use tool like VisualVM to take a thread dump:

[image]

**How read thread dumps:**

Great article: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-read-a-thread-dump

Look for blocked and waiting threads. Probably there will be multiple threads stucked on same line and only one thread making some progress.

**How read thread dumps in your situation:**

I would make a few thread dumps right after the restart and then when problem occurs. If you can distinguish when one thread ends and another one get time for progress I would make another thread dump and compare them (before first end and after second start working).

Answer (score 0):

Websphere has a thread pool for each server.

My understanding from your query is that you have an multithreading program where there is no restriction on the number of threads created.

So, in such a scenario there would be a point where websphere would run out of all the threads in the pool and then would wait for previous threads to close and would assign the new thread to your program as and when a new thread is available in its thread pool.

My first recommendation would be to user Java multithreading framework like Executor pool.
I would recommend that you have a limit on the number of threads to be created.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
//10 is the max number of threads for this threadpool
executor.execute(<your Runnable Object here>);
```

But, if you still do not want to restrict then you can use:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
//This will create thread as and when needed however, this would have a better management of threads as compared to simply creating threads.
executor.execute(<your Runnable Object here>);
```

Please note that still you may run out of threads and memory as there is no limitation.

In Webspehere you can set the number of threads in :
Servers --> All Servers -->  --> Additional Properties --> Thread pools --> WebContainer
**Minimum Size, Maximum Size**

Comment: Given code samples are irrelevant, threading is forbidden in EE environment. You only can use ManagedExecutor (server resource) or asynchrounous calls.

Comment: Can you throw some more light on this ? I have a web application running in Webspehere 8.5.5 ND and weblogic 12 c where I have initiated my thread for doing some healthchecks and its working for around 3-4 years now.

Comment: A vanilla Java SE ThreadPool does not contain Java EE context data on its threads like a Java EE ManagedExecutor does.  If your Java SE ThreadPool's operations do not need Java EE context, it will likely work as you are seeing, but as soon as you need a Java EE context for the work that is processed in the ThreadPool you will run into issues.